# How do you include existing migrations into a VS 2013 project?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-migrations

I excluded some migrations from my project in visual studio and now want to add them back.. I noticed there are 3 files per migration... 2 `.cs` and 1 .`resx`...

When I add them all back and compile, then try and run the migrations via `Update-Database` I get the error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "..." was correctly embedded or linked
>   into assembly "..." at compile time, or that all the satellite
>   assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Answer (score 0):

I selected all of the files and then changed the properties to Embedded Resource